# Why do electrons have rest energy?

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, mass-energy, elementary-particles

E=mc² so inserting the value of m and c we get 0.511 MeV for electron but then what does this energy account for coz according to me electrons are not made up of any particles so this doesn't account for potential energy neither KE then what does it account for why do a free electron at rest have this energy

Comment: As well as the question linked in Dan's answer, also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/how-does-the-higgs-mechanism-work and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426153/mass-of-the-electron

Comment: The electron is made of three preons (anti T rishons).

Comment: @safesphere I saw on internet they cannot be divided further

Comment: I believe the consensus is that there is currently no known substructure for the electron, so it is currently considered an elementary particle. The preon is a model of particle physics (there are many), but there isn't direct experimental evidence to support it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64232/is-the-higgs-boson-not-responsible-for-most-mass

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your profile picture is of Albert Einstein. One of Einstein's major contributions is the concept of [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). It shows that particles have intrinsic energy apart from classically considered mechanical energy. An electron has nonzero rest mass, so it follows that it has nonzero rest energy. Evidence of this can be most easily seen in particle physics, such as electron-positron annihilation.

However, if your question is pertaining to why electrons have mass to begin with, this question pertaining to the Higgs mechanism may interest you: [Is the Higgs boson not responsible for most mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64232/is-the-higgs-boson-not-responsible-for-most-mass)

Comment: No like see why does it have rest energy lets say if we are talking about something which is composed of smaller parts then we can say that the energy is because of interactions between them.. potential energy...but electrons what is the thing giving it energy...I mean ok it's mass but why...what is the intrinsic energy coz electron is not made up of something...so why is there an intrinsic energy

Comment: The mass arises through interaction with the Higgs field. The answers to the question linked in my answer may help you, but if you are still confused, please clarify your question.

Comment: no I mean I am not asking why electron has mass. . I am asking why does it have intrinsic energy...I know formula but what's the logical reasoning...what is that intrinsic energy

Comment: It has rest energy because it has rest mass. And it has rest mass because of the Higgs mechanism. So I guess you could say that its intrinsic energy arises from its interaction with the Higgs field.

Comment: Ye thanks exactly what I was asking...  Higgsfield is the intrinsic force it means.